# Allow main navigation routing from a sidebar component

Tags: angular, components, angular2-routing

I am trying to setup my layout with a sidebar and a main stage area where `router-outlet` will live. I want to make my sidebar a component what will hold my navigation but I have run into a problem as now my menu doesn't work, the menu works if I don't use a component and add my menu straight to the main `AppComponent` but thats not what I would like to do. Here is what I have:

**sidebar.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sidebar',
  template: `<div class="main-nav">
                <ul class="vertical-menu">
                  <li>
                    <a routerLink="notes" routerLinkActive="is-active">Notes</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a routerLink="goals" routerLinkActive="is-active">Goals</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>`
})
export class SidebarComponent { }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-startup-science',
  template: `<app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
             <router-outlet></router-outlet>`
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

**app.routes.ts**

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';

// Components
import { AppComponent } from './containers/app.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'app', component: AppComponent },
];
```

Comment: This shouldn't be a problem. Do you use absolute paths (`notes`, `goals`) with leading `/` or relative paths? I guess we need more information to be able to diagnose the problem.

Comment: what you are showing here according to that `notes` and `goals` both don't exist in `routes.ts`.

Comment: show us error msg too if any.

Comment: I found the problem, I needed to include the router inside the module that container the Sidebar.